# How to create argument resolver in Rook

Tags: clojure

I want to make an [argument resolver](https://portal.aviso.io/#/document/open-source/rook/Current/argument-resolvers.html) in Rook that does a simple transform on an input.  Say I have a simple REST URL like `/resource/1` to get the resource with id `1`.  But the id comes in as `"1"`, i.e. a string.  I don't want to have to convert the id to a string explicitly in every endpoint function.

It seems like I might be able to do this with argument resolvers, for instance I tried this:

```
(def handler (-> (rook/namespace-handler
                  ["resource" 'my-project.resource {'id #(Integer. %)}])
                 rook/wrap-with-standard-middleware))
```

Then in the resource namespace, I would already have the `id` as an integer.

```
(defn show [id]
  ; id should now be an integer
  (r/response (* id 2)))
```

But this doesn't work, `id` is still a string and the resolver never gets called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here: (1) argument resolvers are functions of the request and (2) route params receive special handling that currently takes priority over other applicable resolvers.

(1) means that an argument resolver must ultimately take the form

```
(fn [request]
  …)
```

– for example, you could write a resolver to parse the route param `id` – and just that one – like so:

```
(fn [request]
  (-> request :io.aviso.rook.dispatcher/route-params :id Integer/parseInt))
```

Argument resolver factories take the form

```
(fn [sym]
  ;; usually there'll be a let form here wrapping the inner fn
  (fn [request]
    …))
```

`sym` is the name of the argument being resolved (for example, `:request-key query-params` resolves to `(:query-params request)`).

(2) means that, as of release 0.1.39, registering this as a resolver for the symbol `id` won't work; registering a resolver factory and tagging your `id` parameter with it won't work either.

For now, your best bet is probably to handle your route params in a first-line `let`. Alternatively you can work around default route parameter handling using a resolver factory designed to be applied to a different symbol:

```
;; ATTN: :io.aviso.rook.dispatcher/route-params is an implementation detail
;; NB. this assumes it will be registered under the keyword :route-param
(fn [sym]
  (fn [request]
    (let [route-param-kw (:route-param (meta sym))]
      (assert (keyword? route-param-kw))
      (-> request :io.aviso.rook.dispatcher/route-params route-param-kw))))
```

You'd use it like so:

```
(defn show [^{:route-param :id} foo]
  …)
```

This just gets the raw runtime value of the path fragment, but it can straightforwardly be modified to apply an arbitrary transformation (possibly a function extracted from the metadata on the argument symbol if you need that level of flexibility). Note that you'll want to make sure that the argument resolver doesn't throw if the input doesn't match its expectations.